# Error when compiling Nim file with --os:any

Tags: compiler-errors, cross-compiling, nim-lang

When I try to compile any Nim file with `--os:any` I get this error:

```
osalloc.nim(218, 10) Error: Port memory manager to your platform
```

Why does this error pop up and how can I fix it?

In addition, when I try to compile with `-d:useMalloc` and `--mm:orc/arc/none` it *does* work. However, it only works for files that don't import the `os` module. How do I compile with `--os:any` even with the `os` module imported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--os:any` basically means: no OS support. It is generally used for writing kernels or bare metal microcontroller code where no OS is available. Therefore, it it expected that the `os` module, which provides access to OS services, is not available for `os:any`.

Furthermore, Nim uses a custom memory allocator. If it is not implemented for your platform (such as `os:any`), you can ask nim to use the platform's `malloc` if is available by passing `-d:useMalloc` to the nim compiler.

Comment: see my edit please

Comment: Well, `--os:any` basically means: no OS support, it is generally used for writing kernels or bare metal microcontroller code where no OS is available. Therefore, it it expected, that the `os` module, which access to provides OS services, is not available for `os:any`.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you. Put this as an answer or edit your original answer with this and I will accept it.